# Defining a family of functions $h(f(v),g(v))$ s.t. $f$ maximizes $h$, and $g$ minimizes $h$

Tags: functions, definition

I'm trying to define the collection of functions $H:V\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall h\in H\exists f,g\in V\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall v\in V$:

$f$ "makes" $h$ descend.

$g$ "makes" $h$ ascend.

For example, supposing $\forall v\in V:f(v)> 1,g(v)> 1$:
$$h(v)=f(v)-g(v)$$
$$h(v)=\frac{f(v)}{g(v)}$$
$$h(v)=\sqrt[g(v)]{f(v)}$$

The definition I came up with is:
$$h\in \{ H\in 2^{G:V\to \mathbb{R} }\to \mathbb{R} \| \exists \{ f,g\} \subseteq V\to \mathbb{R} , \forall v\in V\to \mathbb{R} : \frac{\partial}{\partial f}H(v)>0 , \frac{\partial}{\partial g}H(v)<0\}$$
I feel like something is off.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you wrote your final definition in simpler notation. I'm not entirely sure what all of the symbols you've used are at the end so either there is some convention I'm not familiar with or you're being sloppy. Maybe don't be afraid to use some English in the brackets

Comment: When you say “group”, do you mean a set with a binary associative operation that has an identity and inverses, or do you mean “collection”?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin , a collection, I think.